# Twilio JS Client - trying to connect to a "enqueued" call

Tags: javascript, twilio, voice

I am creating a softphone solution using Twilio JS SDK client...

so the inbound is received by my server-side PHP script that enqueues the call with this Twiml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say language="pt-BR">Olá Rodrigo, em breve você será atendido.</Say>
    <Enqueue action="http://xxxx/_api/external/twilio/ura_queueaction.php" waitUrl="http://xxxx/_api/external/twilio/ura_wait.php">CAcb486a96ecd4f458ac0287568d122035</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

.... so after the call gets queued, my webhook is called and now i have the queuesid of this call:

```
QueueSid    "QU34063a138b999bfb28c0b732e84a5a7f"
```

...so now, my internal notification system notified my internal user in our intranet, so using the twilio device object i need to connect this local "agent" to that queued call...i am trying to accomplish this using:

```
var params = {
  To: queuesid
};
if (device) {
  device.connect(params);
}
```

no error is returned, on the console and i receive a message that the call was initiated, but immediately disconnected... i also try to send as the parameter the callsid of the first inbound call, same results.

I search all over the internet for a list of the possible "parameters" for the device.connect("**PARAMS**")....found nothing.

Any good soul here can help me?

Comment: What code are you running/TwiML are you returning from your TwiML application that is set up for Twilio Client?

Comment: i am using JS sdk,,,, but i realized now that i have to edit the twiml returned by my Twilio Function that handles the calls from my JS client. trying to do thast now.

Comment: Cool, let me know how it goes. Also, the params you pass to the connect function will be sent to that Twilio Function, that's how you can use them.

Comment: I recommend you edit your question if you are going to post code 

Answer (score 0):

when i engueued the call i named it "queue-"...like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say language="pt-BR">Olá Rodrigo, em breve você será atendido.</Say>
    <Enqueue action="http://xxxx/_api/external/twilio/ura_queueaction.php" waitUrl="http://xxxxx/_api/external/twilio/ura_wait.php">queue-CAdc202422b5cadcda115bb44912920e3e</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

so, i changed my twilio function code to :

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    if(event.To) {
      // Wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
      // if is a valid phone number
      //const attr = isAValidPhoneNumber(event.To) ? 'number' : 'client';

      re = /^(.*?)-(.*?)+$/;
      var myRe = new RegExp(re, "g");
      var type = myRe[0];
      var destin = myRe[1];

      const dial = twiml.dial({
        callerId: context.CALLER_ID,
      });

      if(type == "phone"){
        dial['number']({}, destin);
      }
      if(type == "client"){
        dial['client']({}, destin);
      }
      if(type == "queue"){
        twiml.dial().queue(event.To)
      }

      //dial[attr]({}, event.To);
    } else {
      twiml.say('Thanks for calling!');
    }

     callback(null, twiml);
};

/**
* Checks if the given value is valid as phone number
* @param {Number|String} number
* @return {Boolean}
*/

function isAValidPhoneNumber(number) {
  return /^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$/.test(number);
}
```

but even then, i am not able to connect to the enqueued call....any clues?

Answer (score 0):

i made it!!!

the problem was indeed on twilio function... here the solution:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    if(event.To) {
      // Wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
      // if is a valid phone number
      //const attr = isAValidPhoneNumber(event.To) ? 'number' : 'client';

      re = /^(.*?)-(.*)+$/;
      var myRe = re.exec(event.To);
      var type = myRe[1];
      var destin = myRe[2];

      if(type == "phone"){
        const dial = twiml.dial({
          callerId: context.CALLER_ID,
          record: 'record-from-ringing-dual'
        });
        dial['number']({}, destin);
      }
      if(type == "client"){
        const dial = twiml.dial({
          callerId: context.CALLER_ID,
          record: 'record-from-ringing-dual'
        });
        dial['client']({}, destin);
      }
      if(type == "queue"){
        const dial = twiml.dial({
          callerId: context.CALLER_ID,
          record: 'record-from-ringing-dual'
        });
        dial['queue']({url: 'http://xxxx/_api/external/twilio/ura_dequeue.php?queue='+destin}, event.To);
//console.log(myRe);

      }

      //dial[attr]({}, event.To);
    } else {
      twiml.say('Thanks for calling!');
    }

     callback(null, twiml);
};
```